# LaTeX example environment

Tags: macros, environments

I was inspired by the following LaTeX document:
http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~djmorin/chap11.pdf
(written by Prof. David Morin from Harvard university)

I would like to produce a similar example environment, as seen in page 11 for a single example (a thick grey line before and after the example text, and also the "Example (...)" and "Solution" titles in each example.)
Also, as in page 15 a thin grey line is separating two consecutive examples.

Any idea how to create an environment with these macros? I might change it a bit but I would like to be able to produce it.

EDIT:

Is it possible to include the \begin{block} in the example and the \end{block} in the solution, so that I don't need to explicitly write it, but only

```
\begin{example}[Rear clock ahead]
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}

\begin{solution}
\lipsum[2]
\end{solution}

\begin{example}[Example 2]
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}

\begin{solution}
\lipsum[2]
\end{solution}
```

And finally, I would rather have a blank line between the "example" and "solution", and also have \blockline have an equal vertical distance from its top and bottom texts. I am just not sure where to put these commands in your definitions.

Thanks.

[image: Framed]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Andro, I merged now your original unregistered account with you new registered account. Most posts and comments here where under still under the first. Both look very identical, so it isn't easy to see the difference right away.

Comment: It isn't possible. The definition of the start is easy but you can not look in the future :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here a simple solution with rule:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ntheorem,lipsum}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem*{example}{Example}
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}
\newlength\outerlinewidth
\newlength\interline
\newlength\hangleft
\newenvironment{block}{%
 \trivlist\item\relax\par%
 \noindent\rlap{\hspace*{-\hangleft}\color{gray}%
   \rule{\dimexpr \hangleft+\linewidth\relax}{\outerlinewidth}%
   }%
 }{\par%
 \noindent\rlap{\hspace*{-\hangleft}\color{gray}%
   \rule{\dimexpr \hangleft+\linewidth\relax}{\outerlinewidth}
   }%
   \endtrivlist}
\newcommand*\blockline{\par\noindent%
       \begingroup\color{gray}%
       \rule{\linewidth\relax}{\interline}\endgroup\par%
}


%Set parameter:
\setlength{\outerlinewidth}{6pt} %height of the outer line
\setlength{\interline}{2pt} %height of the inter line
\setlength{\hangleft}{1cm} % left indention
\begin{document}
\begin{block}
\begin{example}[Rear clock ahead]
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}
\begin{solution}
\lipsum[2]
\end{solution}
\blockline
\begin{example}[Rear clock ahead]
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}
\begin{solution}
\lipsum[2]
\end{solution}
\end{block}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Here a solution with `mdframed`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ntheorem,lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}
\usepackage{showframe}

\mdfdefinestyle{block}{%
   rightmargin=0pt,
   innerrightmargin=0pt,
   skipabove=\topskip,
   skipbelow=\topskip,
   leftline=false,
   rightline=false,
   leftmargin=-1cm,
   innerleftmargin=1cm,
   linecolor=gray,
   linewidth=6pt
}

\newmdenv[style=block,ntheorem]{block}


\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem*{example}{Example}
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}
\newlength\outerlinewidth
\newlength\interline
\newcommand*\blockline{\par\noindent%
       \begingroup\color{gray}%
       \rule{\linewidth\relax}{\interline}\endgroup\par%
}
%Set parameter:
\setlength{\interline}{2pt} %height of the inter line

\begin{document}
\begin{block}
\begin{example}[Rear clock ahead]
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}
\begin{solution}
\lipsum[2]
\end{solution}
\blockline
\begin{example}[Rear clock ahead]
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}
\begin{solution}
\lipsum[2]
\end{solution}
\end{block}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT 2**

Here a solution with `mdframed` in combination with `etoolbox`. Of course you can use the solution without using `mdframed`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ntheorem,lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}
\usepackage{showframe}

\mdfdefinestyle{block}{%
   rightmargin=0pt,
   innerrightmargin=0pt,
   skipabove=\topskip,
   skipbelow=\topskip,
   leftline=false,
   rightline=false,
   leftmargin=-1cm,
   innerleftmargin=1cm,
   linecolor=gray,
   linewidth=6pt
}

\newmdenv[style=block,ntheorem]{block}


\theoremseparator{:}
\theorembodyfont{}
\newtheorem*{example}{Example}
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}

\newtoggle{env:example}
\newtoggle{env:solution}
\newtoggle{env:block}
\settoggle{env:solution}{false}
\settoggle{env:example}{false}
\settoggle{env:block}{false}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{block}%
    {\settoggle{env:block}{true}
     \settoggle{env:solution}{false}
     \settoggle{env:example}{false}}

\AfterEndEnvironment{block}%
    {\settoggle{env:solution}{false}
     \settoggle{env:block}{false}
     \settoggle{env:example}{false}}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{example}%
    {\ifboolexpr{ test {\iftoggle{env:block}}
                  and 
                  test {\iftoggle{env:example}}}%
                 {\settoggle{env:example}{true}}{}
     \iftoggle{env:example}{\blockline}{}}

\AfterEndEnvironment{example}%
    {\settoggle{env:example}{true}}

\newlength\outerlinewidth
\newlength\interline
\newcommand*\blockline{\par\noindent%
       \begingroup\color{gray}%
       \rule{\linewidth\relax}{\interline}\endgroup\par%
}
%Set parameter:
\setlength{\interline}{2pt} %height of the inter line

\begin{document}
\begin{block}
\begin{example}[Rear clock ahead]
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}
\begin{solution}
\lipsum[2]
\end{solution}
%\blockline
\begin{example}[Rear clock ahead]
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}
\begin{solution}
\lipsum[2]
\end{solution}
\end{block}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Nicely done:-) only thing is the text inside the example\solution is set in italics instead of regular text, is there a way to change the theorem definition?

Comment: @Andro: Use `\theoremseparator{:}
\theorembodyfont{}`

Comment: @Andro -- if using `\theorembodyfont{}` it must be stated *before* the `\newtheorem`s to which it applies -- which probably isn't all of them.

Comment: @Marco: Ok. I was wondering if it is possible to enhance this example further, and make the block lines appear automatically with the examples. My idea is for the "example" environment to check if the previous environment is also an example; if it is, a thin line will replace the previous thick line. Otherwise, a thick line will be drawn. at the end of a solution a thick line will always be drawn. I this possible? This way has the advantage that the lines are part of the example, which saves typing effort and also further separates the content from the design.

Comment: @Andro: Have you seen my second edit? Please delete you answer ;-)

Comment: @Marco: Great! thank you. I will now study the details of these examples to learn all about these options and packages.

Comment: Now I tested EDIT and EDIT2 (I didn't have a chance before since I wasn't near a computer with LaTeX). and I get errors. I suspect it has to do with the 'mdframed' package. An image is attached here: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/705/errorso.png

Comment: @Andro: You need an update of your distribution. I added `\mdfdefinestyle` with the newest version.

Comment: @Marco: I have successfully updated my package. But I would like to know if there is a way to automate also the line rules associated with the "block" environment, I have edited my message to clarify what I mean.